# Detect amplitude of audio file per second?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, audio, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to detect the amplitude in dB of an audio file per second using iPhone SDK. I need this functionality for the mouth animation of an object according to the dB magnitude of the sound file per second. How can I do this ? With which audio framework is it possible ?
Do you have any links to any examples ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Have found the solution over this problem

I have used the AVAudioPlayer's peakPowerForChannel and averagePowerForChannel method for getting the decibles

```
  AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];
    avPlayer.delegate = self;

    avPlayer.meteringEnabled = YES;
     [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
     [avPlayer play];


 NSTimer *levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

This method is return the peakPowerForChannel and averagePowerForChannel

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {

    [avPlayer updateMeters];
    NSLog(@"Peak left: %f Avg right: %f", [avPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0],[avPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0]);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems good, don't know any iPhone programming though sorry:
http://www.politepix.com/2010/06/18/decibel-metering-from-an-iphone-audio-unit/

Comment: i had watched this link but i not understand the code snippet

Comment: I'd recommend pulling the code into Xcode, and studying it until you do understand, this is the way to do it!

Comment: i don,t understand how to call the recorded file with the rendercallback function for Remote IO.